# Android Aligning Element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Im having trouble aligning my button and textbox at the bottom of the page. Also may relative layout messed up. How do I add a view with the current conversation. my Listview is not working. I want to attain a simple design like this

[image]

here is my code. Also the grey is overlaying my app and i can't see my listview

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
  <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but my output looks like this

[image]

Comment: check my ans and also see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/send" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <Button android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send" 
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: how do i make the send button stock and won't move when i have 3 lines?

Comment: @Cindy93 it'll in `center` you need to fix that in bottom.

Answer (score 0):

you should put your EditText and Button inside a LinerLayout(horizontal)

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" <!-- or give some dimension -->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
        />

    <Button android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <Button android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send" 
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="send" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

It is looking like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a `LinearLayout` inside your main relative layout, and add your `EditText` and `Button` inside that `LinearLayout`. Don't forgat to add property `android:layout_weight="1"` to your elements. like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/send" />

 </LinearLayout>
```